# Stop Python Script from Writing to File after it reaches a certain size in linux

Tags: python, linux, twitter

Somewhat new to Python and new to linux.  I created a script that mines Twitter's streaming API.  Script writes to a .csv file when things in the stream match my parameters.

I'd like to know if there's any way to stop my script once the file has reached 1 gig.  I know cron can be used to time the script and everything, but I'm more concerned about the file size than the time it takes.

Thanks for your input and consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you probably don't need `os.stat` and `os.stat` may give you a false size in some cases (namely buffers not flushing). Why not just use `f.tell()` to read the size with something like this

```
with open('out.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csvfile = csv.writer(f)
    maxsize = 1024                # max file size in bytes
    for row in data():
        csvfile.writerow(row)
        if f.tell() > maxsize:    # f.tell() gives byte offset, no need to worry about multiwide chars
            break
```

Comment: Works great.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Use python's `os.stat()` to get info on the file, then check the total number of bytes of the existing file (`fileInfo.st_size`) plus the size of the data you are about to write.

```
import os
fileInfo = os.stat('twitter_stream.csv')
fileSize = fileInfo.st_size
print fileSize

# Now get data from twitter
# determine number of bytes in data
# write data if  file size + data bytes < 1GB
```

Comment: Worked great as well.  Thanks for helping me out with this.