# How to write to multiple CSV files with a max size

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So right now I am combining many json files, transforming the data then writing out as rows to a CSV file. The problem is that this data will grow exponentially, and I may run into memory errors in the future.

How would I go about writing to CSV, but once the file size is greater than 1GB start writing to a new file?

This is my code for writing to one file:

```
with open('foo.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    for response_row in load_json():
        try:
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="|")
            writer.writerow(row)

        except Exception as e:
            logging.critical(str(e))
```

Comment: is 1GB limit on CSV file max size?

Comment: That is what I would like yes

Comment: If its the limit then I would write into multiple files.

Comment: @Prateek that's _precisely_ what the OP is asking about. They want to automatically start writing to a new file if the current one approaches their limit.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/02/11/python-how-to-create-rotating-logs/

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the other question as marked.

For the user asking the question, if you're writing the file line-by-line, you could add up the lengths of each line and swap to a new write file when the sum of lengths reaches a threshold (each character is one byte).

Comment: @ividito isn't that what [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) does already?

Comment: @ividito I think that is the only way to go. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I'll look into [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) too. Seems like it could help in this case

Comment: @jdoe That first link I commented shows a usage of it as well. I might try to write something for fun with it (I've never used it before, only read about it)

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce it is a method in the `logging` library though. It seems exactly what the OP wants, but I'm not sure it's a good solution to their current setup or how to implement it cleanly with CSV

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Thank you for the answer I'll give it a try, and if it doesn't work I'll manually do it as ividito suggested

Comment: @roganjosh I know, that's why it might be a fun experiment to implement it with csvs

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I suspect it would also make a good answer at the end :) I'll have a quick scan for dupes

Comment: @roganjosh Well, I'm sure you'll beat me to it (you are fast!) but I might try anyways!

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Oh no, I'm not going to try implement it myself, you can have that :) But I'm going to check whether there is a clean solution to the problem already (since, for now you can't post anything with this being tagged as a dupe). I think that tag might need to be removed.

Comment: I suspect that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430555/stop-python-script-from-writing-to-file-after-it-reaches-a-certain-size-in-linux) would be a decent starting point inside a loop to open a new file

Comment: @martineau Based on the comment trail, I don't think the dupe target is appropriate. The OP seems to be looking for something like the [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) from the `logging` module but for CSV output. In other words, a continuous process.

Comment: It's not duplicate. The link given was splitting file..Here it's the opposite

Comment: why would writing files > 1GB cause a memory issue?  You're not holding the file in memory all at once, you're just writing to the file.

Comment: @Constance It is just to future proof the script. The data will be growing exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a proxy class that takes a base filename and a max file size, and creates a new file and closes the current file when the file size exceeds the limit upon writing a line:

```
from typing import IO
from io import TextIOBase

class SizeCappingFileWriter(TextIOBase, IO[str]):
    def __init__(self, filename, maxsize):
        self.filename = filename
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self.count = 0
        self.file = None

    def write(self, value):
        if not self.file:
            self.count += 1
            self.file = open(
                f'{self.filename}.{self.count}', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
        self.file.write(value)
        if value.endswith('\n') and self.file.tell() > self.maxsize:
            self.file.close()
            self.file = None

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.file:
            self.file.close()
```

so that:

```
import csv

with SizeCappingFileWriter('test.csv', 15) as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for _ in range(8):
        writer.writerow(range(3))
```

results in the following files:

```
# test.csv.1
0,1,2
0,1,2
0,1,2

# test.csv.2
0,1,2
0,1,2
0,1,2

# test.csv.3
0,1,2
0,1,2
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/PitifulPepperyOmnipage